# Why is that Pandas to numpy array conversion yields different results with the inclusion of brackets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The shape of the numpy array(converted from a Dataframe) displays different results with the inclusion and exclusion of brackets[]

I'm using here the housing.csv file.
I explored the documentation but couldn't find any reason behind it.
Please dont mark it duplicate .

```
x=data[['TV','radio']]
y=data[['sales']]
```

and then when I convert them into numpy array and check the shape with

```
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)

y.shape
```

it shows y as (200, 1)
and in the other case when I assign x and y as

```
x=data[['TV','radio']]
y=data['sales']
```

It shows the shape of y as (200, )

Why is that? What does it mean (200, ) ? is it a array or a matrix

Comment: An array with shape `(x,)`, like a series, has only one dimension, denoted by single-value tuple. See marked duplicate for more details.